# Custom Post Type setup

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, query, archives

Desired behavior:

Custom Post Type slug: researchers, students, collaborators
URL: http://domainexample.com/people/researchers, http://domainexample.com/people/students, http://domainexample.com/people/collaborators
Template File: archive-people.php

How should I setup my Custom Post Type to achieve this behavior?
And I wanted to do it without using Taxonomies.
Possible?

Tried to set the `has_archive` slug and the `rewrite` slug to `people/researchers`, and the posts are loaded although the loaded template file still falls to arquive.php.

Current 'researchers' Custom Post Type registration code:

```
$args = array(
    "label" => __( "Researchers", "" ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "",
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => true,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "has_archive" => "people/researchers",
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "people/researchers", "with_front" => true ),
    "query_var" => true,
    "supports" => array( "title" ),
);
register_post_type("researchers", $args);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set any arbitrary path in the `rewrite` `slug` and `has_archive` arguments:

```
$args = array(
    'rewrite'     => array('slug' => 'people/researchers'),
    'has_archive' => 'people/researchers',
    // other args...
);
```

**EDIT**

Your post type slug is `researchers`, so WordPress will be looking for the file `archive-researchers.php` by default. If you want to force a different template, you can use the `archive_template` filter:

```
function wpd_researchers_archive_template( $archive_template ){
     if( is_post_type_archive( 'researchers' ) ){
          $archive_template = locate_template( 'archive-people.php' );
     }
     return $archive_template;
}
add_filter( 'archive_template', 'wpd_researchers_archive_template' );
```

Comment: I tried setting the rewrite slug, the archive slug and even the query_var but the template file loaded still falls to archive.php… (the posts are loaded though).

Comment: add your current post type registration code to your question.

Comment: I have updated my question with the registration code. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Your code doesn’t show the post type slug you pass to `register_post_type`, that is what will dictate the correct template file name.

Comment: I'm passing the 'researchers' slug to `register_post_type`. I need it to be 'researchers' and not 'people' because I have other CPT's I want to fall into the same behavior. Sorry if that wasn't clear. Is there a way to rewrite the slug passed to register_post_type and get the correct template file name?

Comment: see edit above.

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer.
Am I correct that, in this example, it's not mandatory to set the rewrite slug? At first, I thought the rewrite slug would precisely change the register slug but, apparently, that's not the case!

Comment: If you don't set a rewrite slug, it'll default to whatever you pass as the first argument to `register_post_type`, which in your case is `researchers`.

Comment: Do you know mean to grab the template or in the query loop?